# what does this sentence mean in given text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Creating this site has given Disney fans the easy-to-consume articles everyone loves with Buzzfeed, but with the best flair possible – Disney flair.

I think it means that the article are as easy as articles of Buzzfeed but with different scent.

Comment: I strongly recommend editing those "dose"s. It's spelled "does".

Answer (score 1):

"Disney flair" is a set of stylistic features that are associated with this particular corporate entity, i.e. those stylistic treatments that are recognizable as bearing the stamp of the "Disney brand".

Answer (score 1):

See "[Flair: definition #2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flair)" -

> "an unusual and appealing quality or style; a uniquely attractive
>   quality or style."

It means they've used easy-to-consume online content made popular by sites like Buzzfeed (short quizzes, photo galleries, short articles), and used it as a model to create a similar site with Disney-specific content and style.

The "best flair possible" means they believe Disney's own unique style & qualities offer the best way to enjoy that kind of content. They're promoting the website & hoping you'll visit.